# How can I do automatic uid for docs in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to do a group system for a flutter app and I need to store it in firebase, and every group has his own ID, it's called "groupID". How to do programmatically that every new group create has his "groupID" create automatically. Is organized like this:

[image]

In other words, how can I do in the code to fill the Groups column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flutter,

1. Let firestore creates document reference with it's automatic document ID

```
DocumentReference docRef = firestore.collection('Groups').document();
print(docRef.documentID);
docRef.setData({JSON Data});
```

2. Providing your own document ID for groups

```
String groupID = 'unique_id'
DocumentReference docRef = firestore.collection('Groups').document(groupID);
print(docRef.documentID);
docRef.setData({JSON Data});
```

For constraints on document ID - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields

Comment: Thank you very much, it work. But now the syntax is a little different its something like this:DocumentReference docRef=FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Groups').doc();